# How to make nextjs <Image /> circular

Tags: image, image-processing, next.js, nextjs-image

How do you create a circular image using nextjs Image? I have found that the solution involving wrapping the image in divs with border radius and hidden overflow isn't working.

```
import Image from 'next/image'

<Image src={props.profilePictureURL}  height={200} width={200} alt='IMG2'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css file.

```css
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
<Image src={props.profilePictureURL}  className={styles.makeImageCircular} height={200} width={200} alt='IMG2'/>
```

where:

```
.makeImageCircular {
  border-radius:50%;
}
```

*mistakenly set 50% to '50%' (within a string in CSS)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@rodrigodh's answer seems to make **ALL** of your `img` elements fully rounded, this may be considered bad practice in a real world scenario (depending on your use case). If this is not the desired effect, you can add inline style to a specific Next.js Image component:

```
style={{ borderRadius: '50%', overflow: 'hidden', width: 24, height: 24 }}
```

@421's answer seems to use SCSS where the `styles` prop is used. Again, if you don't use this method, you can just use inline styles or use your CSS in whatever way you prefer.

On the Next.js [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image) for the Image component, they use inline styles but pass the object via a named variable to the custom `style` prop on `Image` like this:

```
const imageStyle = {
  borderRadius: '50%',
  border: '1px solid #fff',
};
 
export default function ProfileImage() {
  return <Image src="..." style={imageStyle} />;
}
```

But do note, you may need

> overflow: 'hidden'

depending on your Next.js version (can't be too specific here, I am on 13.1.6 and I **do** need it). The height and width styles are also often required, even though these same properties are added to the `Image` component themselves (and are **required** props, along with "alt").

The same can be done if you use TailwindCSS:

```
className='rounded-full overflow-hidden w-[24px] h-[24px]'
```

As a footnote on TailwindCSS, the last time I tried the Next.js docs approach I couldn't seem to get the inline style they provide to work on 13.1.6 when using MantineUI, so I use this approach and wrap the `Image` in a surrounding `div`:

```
<div className='flex items-center'>
  {users?.map((user: User) => {
    return <div
      key={id}
      className='border-2 border-indigo-500 rounded-full overflow-hidden w-[28px] h-[28px]'
    >
      <Image
        width={24}
        height={24}
        src={user.photo}
        alt='user_photo'
      />
    </div>
  })}
</div>
```

Happy rounding! - A developer that already had this problem.